# How to create a jks file before Spring boot starts?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to run a method that builds a .keystore file, but this file must to be created before the application starts, how can I do that?

Step by step of I want to do:

step 1: Run a method that read an environment variable, decodes this value and from this, creates a file that's called "keystore.jks"

step 2: Starts my spring boot application and it using the application.properties, use the path of the keystore.jks created previously

Comment: Can you describe your setup a bit more please? "run a method" - Java method? How do you start your java application, when you want to run a method before it starts? Does it need to be created every time, or just once, manually?

Comment: You probably want to use it for private key/ssl cerifcate storage? This is pre-execution  steps, ideally you should have separate script( shell script/command line) to create require file as part of deployment process.

Comment: @cyberbrain 

about my setup... my spring boot starts like this

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
 }

and in my application properties I have a property where I use a keystore, like secure.something = jks/keystore.jks, and this is the file that I need to create with a java method (Idk if I have other option using spring)

Answer (score 0):

A usual Spring Boot App does this at start-up:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // do anything you want here
    // ...
    
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
```

As stated in the comment, you can do anything at this point before Spring.

**But**, it won't run in the context of Spring: no injection, no properties loading, etc.

Comment: I tried to run my method as you said, but this exception occurs 

 Cannot invoke "String.getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)" because "src" is null

Comment: You should post your code and the stack trace.